# Regex, substitute part of a string always at the end

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to substitute a string so a part of this url always goes to the end

```
google.com/to_the_end/faa/
google.com/to_the_end/faa/fee/
google.com/to_the_end/faa/fee/fii
```

Using this

```
(google\.com)\/(to_the_end)\/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)

$1/$3/$2
```

It works for the first example, but I need something a bit more versatile so no matter how many folders it always moves `to_the_end` as the last folder in the url string

Desired output

```
google.com/faa/to_the_end
google.com/faa/fee/to_the_end/
google.com/faa/fee/fii/to_the_end/
```

Comment: I assume it would be as simple as using `(.*)` as last group. What exactly is not working with your current approach?

Comment: `/(google\.com)\/(to_the_end)\/(.+)/` should work

Comment: `(google\.com)\/(to_the_end)\/(.*[^\/])\/?$` will work even if there is a `/` at the end ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/mGm46l/2)).

Comment: @knittl using that gives me this for the first results `google.com/foo//to_the_end` Would have to do `$1/$3$2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(google\.com)\/(to_the_end)\/(.*[^\/])\/?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mGm46l/2).

*Details*:

- `(google\.com)` - Group 1: `google.com`
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `(to_the_end)` - Group 2: `to_the_end`
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `(.*[^\/])` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a char other than a `/` char
- `\/?` - an optional `/` char
- `$` - end of string.