# Regex Replace that works with and without trailing slash

Tags: string, regex-replace

I am trying to match a url string and I want to swap when some word is included in this case `reviews` the problem is that when the url ends on a forward slash my formula adds a double slash. Is there a way to add a slash only when there is no slash at the end?

https://regex101.com/r/cjMEiW/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is there a way to add a slash only when there is no slash at the end?*

The **'trick'** is to use an additional 'dummy' (not used in substitution) group `(\/?)` which can be empty or contain a slash and not to allow the group 3 to include a slash at its end `(.*[^\/$])`

See:
https://regex101.com/r/nysBYY/2

Regex:

```
(<a href='https:\/\/www\.example\.com)\/(reviews)\/(.*[^\/$])(\/?)('>)
```

Test string:

```
<a href='https://www.example.com/reviews/citroen/c4/'>here</a>
<a href='https://www.example.com/reviews/citroen/c4'>here</a>
```

Substitution:

```
$1/$3/$2/$5
```

Output:

```
<a href='https://www.example.com/citroen/c4/reviews/'>here</a>
<a href='https://www.example.com/citroen/c4/reviews/'>here</a>
```

Check out the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72516646/7711283 at [Regex, substitute part of a string always at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72516522/regex-substitute-part-of-a-string-always-at-the-end) for more detailed explanation of the regex of the groups.

---

P.S. the OPs regex was:

---

```
(<a href='https:\/\/www\.example\.com)\/(reviews)\/(.*)('>)
```

with substitution `$1/$3/$2/$4` which resulted in:

```
<a href='https://www.example.com/citroen/c4//reviews/'>here</a>
<a href='https://www.example.com/citroen/c4/reviews/'>here</a>
```